# Android Studio Intermittent HttpsURLConnection Failure

Tags: android, android-studio, httpurlconnection

I have multiple applications using the same code to make a HttpsURLConnection to a server. Occasionally I am unable to make any communication with a device, but a different device running the same HttpsURLConnection code to the same server address works no problem.

Sometimes the first device will make connection after multiple attempts seemingly by itself. However resetting the wifi connection on the device always fixes it immediately.

This has lead me to believe the router connected to the server is dropping the device from its routing table, but I would appreciate an extra pair of eyes on the code.

I have a separate activity to make the HttpsURLConnection with the following code:

```
class WebRequest {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
private final static int POST = 2;

//Constructor with no parameter
public WebRequest() {

}

/**
 * Making web service call
 *
 * @url - url to make request
 * @requestmethod - http request method
 */
public String makeWebServiceCall(String url, int requestmethod) {
    return this.makeWebServiceCall(url, requestmethod, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 *
 * @url - url to make request
 * @requestmethod - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 */
private String makeWebServiceCall(String urladdress, int requestmethod,
                                  HashMap<String, String> params) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urladdress);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        if (requestmethod == POST) {
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } else if (requestmethod == GET) {
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }

        if (params != null) {
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");

                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            writer.write(result.toString());

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        }

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

}
```

I am calling that code from another activity using this within an Asynctask:

```
WebRequest webreq = new WebRequest();

request = webreq.makeWebServiceCall(URL, WebRequest.GET);
```

I am concerned that something within the code is causing intermittent connection issues within that device. One thing I have noticed is that there is no connection.disconnect.

Thank you for any insight into this issue!

Comment: It has nothing to do with your code. But with that device as you explained.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. One thing I forgot to add is the device that stops making the HttpUrlConnections is able to connect to the Internet through other apps, YouTube, Google est. But the Internet and server are both on the same router.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short after months of debugging and testing I found the problem..... microwaves in the break room.

Yep; the seemingly random nature of the wifi dropping was due to interference from microwaves being used on the other side of the wall where the antenna was fixed.